# Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to post from my html page and getting following error.
However it works fine from PostMan.I have implemented it using generics.GenerivAPIView.But getting error which says

```
AssertionError: Expected view OrganisationListView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "id". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
[10/Jul/2018 08:30:09] "OPTIONS /api/client/Organisation/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14720
```

and this is my api

```
class OrganisationListView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                           mixins.ListModelMixin,
                           mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                           mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                           mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                           mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    serializer_class = OrganisationSerilizer
Organisation.objects.get(id=self.request.Organisation.id)
    queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
    # allowed_methods = ('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'HEAD', 'DELETE')
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
    filter_class = OrganisationFilter
    ordering_fields = ('name','active')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    # for key
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            print("get called with")
            return self.retrieve(request, id)
        else:
            print("get called without ID")
            return self.list(request)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        print(request.data)
        print("Hello")
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save()
    def put(self, request, id=None):
        return self.update(request, id)
    def delete(self,request,id=None):
        print(request.data)
        print(id)
        return self.destroy(request,id)
```